# Draw the HUD just once on the canvas

Tags: 2d, javascript, rendering, html5, html-canvas

I am not able to draw only one HUD of my game on a separate canvas, so I do not have to redraw it to each frame, I have four functions, **init()**, **render()**, **loop()** and **drawHUD()**:

init() is my function that I call when starting the game, right at the end of the script.

**render()** is my rendering function

**loop()** is my game loop function (do not notice it, I've simplified it with minimal to leave the code cleaner for reading)

**drawHUD()** is my function to draw HUD on Canvas **HUD_CANVAS**

The problem is that the code below does not work, the screen remains blank, but if I put **drawHUD()** inside the render() before `CTX.drawImage (HUD_CANVAS, 0, 0);` then it works and I can see the image on the screen, however I wish I could draw only once, not every frame, since my HUD will not always be updating.

What am I doing wrong?

> *index.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Test</title>

    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        canvas {
            padding: 0;
            margin: auto;
            display: block;
            width: 640px;
            height: 480px;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            border: 1px solid #999;
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body>

    <canvas id="canvas" style="z-index: 0;" width="640" height="480"></canvas>
    <canvas id="hud-canvas" style="z-index: 1;" width="640" height="480"></canvas>

    <script>
    const CANVAS = document.getElementById('canvas');
    const CTX = CANVAS.getContext('2d');
    const HUD_CANVAS = document.getElementById('hud-canvas');
    const HUD_CTX = HUD_CANVAS.getContext('2d');

    function drawHUD() {
        const imgHUD = new Image();
        imgHUD.src = './hand_hud_maya.png';
        HUD_CTX.drawImage(imgHUD, 0, 0, 96, 96, 0, 0, 96, 96);
    }


    function init() {
        drawHUD();
        loop();
    }


    function render() {
        CTX.drawImage(HUD_CANVAS, 0, 0);
    }

    function loop() {
        render();
        requestAnimationFrame(loop);
    }

    init();

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Example:

https://jsfiddle.net/twkq0sn6/

> Up1:

Change that part of the function, I can see the red rectangle on the screen, so I think the problem is with the drawImage() function, but I do not know what it can be, I already tested several images, I do not think it's the image.

```
 function drawHUD() {
     HUD_CTX.fillStyle = "red";
     HUD_CTX.fillRect(50, 50, 50, 50);
 }
```

the image is loaded properly, I can see in the chrome network tab the preview of it, all OK. I do not get any errors, it's hard to figure out where I'm going wrong.

Comment: "I am not able to draw only one HUD of my game on a separate canvas, so I do not have to redraw it to each frame" Why are you not able to do this? Can you show us your intended appearance versus what you see now?

Comment: @DMGregory I'm showing in the above code, when the drawHUD() function is in the loop() it works, but when it's init() does not work.

Comment: @DMGregory here's the example: https://jsfiddle.net/n3s2u60z/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on your answer, you definitely need to preload all your resources before even starting the game. So your process would be

preload_assets ==> Start_game

Here's an extract from [this great article](https://codeincomplete.com/posts/javascript-game-foundations-loading-assets/) on asset loading in HTML5 games:

```
function loadImages(names, callback) {  
  var n,name,
      result = {},
      count  = names.length,
      onload = function() { if (--count == 0) callback(result); };

  for(n = 0 ; n < names.length ; n++) {
    name = names[n];
    result[name] = document.createElement('img');
    result[name].addEventListener('load', onload);
    result[name].src = "images/" + name + ".png";
  }

}
```

Now to run the game you pretty much do something like `loadImages([...], startGameLoop);`

**EDIT: Always set the `onload` event** *before* **you set the `src` attribute.**

Otherwise, you image could finish loading before your onload event fires which means you never get the image drawn on screen.

Answer (score 1):

I found the error, the image was being called in **drawImage()** before it was loaded, unfortunately I did not receive any error that could inform me of this. But I did work by changing the function to:

```
function drawHUD() {
    const imgHUD = new Image();
    imgHUD.src = './my_hud_image.png';
    imgHUD.onload = function(){
        HUD_CTX.drawImage(imgHUD, 0, 0, 256, 256, 0, 0, 256, 256);
    };
    imgHUD.onerror = function(){
        alert("Image error.");
    };
}
```

I think it will be interesting to load all the images and hunting for their possible errors in a separate script called *resources.js* by example, where I load everything that is necessary for the game to run, before it starts.

to read more about Image:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Using_images

Answer (score 0):

```
const CANVAS = document.getElementById('canvas');
const CTX = canvas.getContext('2d');
const HUD_CANVAS = document.getElementById('hud-canvas');
const HUD_CTX = canvas.getContext('2d');
```

Did you mean to get your HUD context from the HUD canvas, instead of from the same canvas used for the main game context?

```
const HUD_CTX = HUD_CANVAS.getContext('2d');
```

Comment: I typed it fast, did not realize it, but it is not that, the problem continues.